# Удалять текст EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть касомная edit вьюшка:

```
<com.sai.android.features.common.widget.CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/nameView"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@color/other_black"
                app:fontType="regular"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_18"/>
```

По умолчанию в неё сэтится текст, после чего я могу удалить его и написать нужный. Как возможно сделать так, чтоб по нажатию на текст, который стоит по умолчанию, он сразу весь удалялся и я мог писать не удаляя ничего в ручную?

Comment: Когда `View` получает фокус, проверяете текст, который находится в ней, если он эквивалентен дефолтному – удаляете его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // code to execute when EditText got focus
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то нужно добавить EditText свойство hint.

```
android:hint=""
```

Это по сути является подсказкой, которая отображается до того момента, пока пользователь на нее не кликнул.

Answer (score 2):

Делал не так давно в своем проекте подобное, только на котлине, но для наглядности думаю пример подойдёт:

```java
nameView.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus && nameView.text.toString() == getString(R.string.nameView)) {
        nameView.text.clear()
    }
}
```

Здесь так раз таки сравниваем если ваш текст в фокусе и текст совпадает с необходимым, после чего зачищаем поле.